# Runtime configs in nextjs

Tags: next.js, frontend

I'm trying to setup my nextjs app to use runtime configurations. Basically, I have an endpoint url that needs to be available trough docker env vars.
I configured following these docs  but it isn't working. My app still using default values from .env file. Could anyone help to understand what I missed or did wrong?
Thanks!

docs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

steps:
1- added to my next.config.js

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_HOST: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_HOST,
},
```

2- retrieved config in my pages

```js
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
const baseURL = publicRuntimeConfig.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_HOST
```

3- created a custom app to setup getInitialProps

> Runtime configuration won't be available to any page (or component in a page) without getInitialProps.

```js
import App from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  return { ...appProps }
}
export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine in your code, tested in a fresh project and everything worked correctly. Therefore I think the issue is that you don't actually have `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_HOST` env var set when you're running `next start`. Btw, you don't need to use the `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix in this kind of usage. If you want build time args you can use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to have the var be available both client and server side by just using `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_` anywhere. Note that in that case the value will be inlined at build time, so the env var needs to be present during build.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried but it still returns undefined. May I configured something still wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I just tested out and turns out `NEXT_PUBLIC_` is not indeed the issue. Everything works fine for me so I actually think you might not have `NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_HOST` env var set when you run `next start`. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: basically my requirements are: i need to provide an endpoint url read at runtime from our docker env configurations in a k8s cluster. runtime, not build time. one docker image that will dynamically load the config from different environments that I run the application. 
We created a example app with all current configuration to show the ideia. May I configured something still wrong?
https://github.com/rafaela2/hello-world-next